# Excel - filling fields based on a day and month of a date field

Tags: microsoft-excel

*edited as my first post was confusing as hell*

*I have also cut this down to just the core bits*

I have a workbook with 2 sheets.  Times and events.
In times, I have the dates (A), extending into the future and a field for events(B):
[image]

In events, I have the dates (A) and description (B) of reoccurring events.
[image]

What I am looking to do is, If the day and month in Times!A matches the day and month in Events!A then display the event description from Events!B in Times!B

I have a different cell in the original workbook where i was looking up public holidays and flagging days as such but that was a 1 to 1 lookup on dates and a vlookup for the information.
I have been trying to twist that into this reoccurring process but just keep ending up with a broken formulas.

Comment: This is bit confusing, `From Events! day and month = the date in times!A` !! , I you sound have to compare Date & Month both between Sheets,, if YES,, please confirm through comments and better [edit] the post & share some screen shot along with formula/method you have been tried so far.

Comment: use a nested formula like `=ifna(vlookup(...),"")`. I leave it to you to figure out the `...`

Comment: edited the original request and added pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*An array (CSE) formula wrapped with `IFERROR` along with `Helper Column` can solve the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

*To create Helper Column:*

- Enter this formula in `Event Sheet's` cell `AB2`:

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK(Time!V2),"",DAY(Time!V2)&MONTH(Time!V2))
  ```
- Formula in `Event Sheet's` cell `AC2`:

`=IF(ISBLANK(Y2),"",DAY(Y2)&MONTH(Y2))`

- An array formula in `Time Sheet's` cell `W2`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Event!Z$2:Z$12,SMALL(IF(Event!AC$2:AC$12=Event!$AB2,ROW(Event!Z$2:Z$12)-MIN(ROW(Event!Z$2:Z$12))+1),COLUMNS(Event!$Z$2:Z2))),"")}
  ```

---

**Edited:**

OP has raised a good point that few dates like `11/02/2020` and `01/12/2020` will return `112` in Helper Column and will confuse Excel to produce wrong results.

So, to avoid this,

- Enter this formula in cell `AB2:`

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK(Time!V2),"",TEXT(DAY(Time!V2),"ddd")&MONTH(Time!V2))
  ```
- Use this in cell `AC2:`

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK(Y2),"",TEXT(DAY(Y2),"ddd")&MONTH(Y2))
  ```

**N.B.**

*Formula in `W2` will remain unchanged.*

---

**N.B.**

- Finish formula in `W2` with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.
- For neatness, later on you may hide helper column.

Comment: Hi,
i'd never have gotten to that formula..  just trying to get it working now.

One thing, I see what you are doing with pulling the day and month out to a field and comparing them but only using short numbers could give errors if i'm understanding this correctly.
e.g. the 11th of feb would be 112.  the 1st of dec would also be 112 would it not?
I'm thinking that, to get a correct 2 digit day and month i'd have to precede with a nominal number like 1, then a 2 digit day and 2 digit month so 11th of feb would be 11102 and the 1st of dec would be 10112. the starting 1 ensuring days are 2 #

Comment: @IanMcGuinness,, you have raised a good point let me check the dates U have given,, actually I've tried with the dates U have given and is working,,, !

Comment: @IanMcGuinness,, check the edited part in my post,, solves the issue, I've tried with all possible combinations and is working. **Remember using *HELPER COLUMN* is the need of the situation and U could not avoid this**.

Comment: Ok, so the text part lets it keep the leading 0 if one is there.
One point, with ddd i was getting thu3 as a result. changed it to dd and got 053 which is what i think you were going for.

Comment: @IanMcGuinness,,, it's basic `dd` formats and returns day in numbers but `ddd` or even `dddd` day of the week like `Tue` or `Tuesday`,, better go with `ddd`. What I've suggested is I think best possible,,, if U have any other/new idea please post,, will help the community.

Comment: Ok, but, again correct me if i'm wrong, ddd + m for the 2nd of april would give thu4.  The 9th of april would also give thu4... etc.
by making it dd+m the 2nd is 024 and the 9th is 094 etc.
I had difficulty understanding / getting the W2 formula to work (not sure i understand what the ctrl+shiht+enter does or if i was doing it right so i replaced it with a test to see if it exists and then a vlookup to get the data.  tested and working well.  thanks for your help.  Ian

Comment: @IanMcGuinness,, glad to help ,, keep asking ☺. Problem like your needs adjustments,,, since in that situation one single method may work or may not with few data,, 1st I've suggested you to use Numeric value of Day & Month then question got twist,, 2nd is Day is alphabets + Month in Numbers, working with most of DATE values, now to adjust another twists, you may use all Day+Month+Year to match with, and is the adjustment required.

Comment: **Continue,,,** And I can say possibly while using Day+Month+Year , one of two Date value may be identical,, in that situation U need to add one another value to your date set,  like TAG no or any Unique IDs. I've shown you the best possible method by using shared data along with twists,, hope this help U.